# How do I replace a word with a new line and a word using regex with an empty string in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, powershell-ise

How do I replace a word with a new line and a word using regex with an empty string in Powershell?

Below is a sample content... I need to delete all the `use database`  and  `go` I'm using powershell and powershell_ise for editor:

> use database_instance
>
> go
>
> if condition

Comment: use `\n` to match newline

Comment: it does not work... I actually tried this..

$out -replace "/use database_\w+\n\w+/g"

Comment: why use `_` in your regex? you can try this: `/use database\n\s*\w+/g`

Comment: sorry forgot to mentioned that there should be an underscore, after the underscore there should be an instance name.

Comment: Edit your question to show what you want the output to look like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match `Newline` and also `space` after the newline:

```
/use database_\w+\n\s*\w+/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
$sql = @"
use database_instance

go

if condition
"@

$sql -ireplace 'use\s+\w+_\w+\s*(?:\r?\n)+\s*go' , ''
```

### How this Works:

1. Using `-ireplace` for case insensitive regex.
2. Find the word `use` followed by one or more whitespace `\s+` followed by one or more word characters `\w+`, then an underscore `_`.
3. One or more word characters `\w+`, followed by 0 or more whitespace (just in case)
4. A non-capturing group `(?:)` since we don't need the result, this is just to encapsulate a newline that accounts for windows and unix line endings. It consists of an optional CR followed by a LF, and this is matched 1 or more times.
5. Followed by 0 or more whitespace `\s*` then the word `go`.
6. Replace it with nothing!

This does leave some empty space, but that shouldn't be too big of an issue since the SQL parser won't care.

#### Note

In your comments you said you tried:

```powershell
$out -replace "/use database_\w+\n\w+/g"
```

Be aware that powershell does not use `/regexhere/` syntax. The forward slashes are treated as literals, so the flags you specified are as well. The replace is global by default so you don't need `g` anyway.

Comment: Your sample works, but when I try it on my data, it does not work.. don't know why... my data came from a batch file it fetches the stored procedure and put it on a variable which is the "$out" variable.

Comment: Post the output of `[RegEx]::Escape($out)`

Comment: Please see below..


use\ margining_prd\ go\ \ IF\ EXISTS\

Comment: Still not replacing, In the powershell, I used the dllgen.bat to connect to the sybase and get the sp that i wanted. and then the save it to the output variable ($out)... after that need to remove some stuff in the string (SP)...